# What is the use of @nullable in OnCreate(@nullable Bundle savedInstances);?

Tags: android, annotations, oncreate, activity-lifecycle

what is the use of @nullable and in what situation not using @nullable be a problem in `onCreate(@nullable Bundle SavedInstances);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely ignore/remove `@nullable` from `OnCreate(@nullable Bundle savedInstances);` as it denotes the parameter, `Bundle` can be null and it has no role at runtime [See the Documentation here for more details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Nullable.html)

Answer (score 1):

> **Nullable**
>
> Denotes that a parameter, field or method return value can be null.
>
> When decorating a method call parameter, this denotes that the
>   parameter can legitimately be null and the method will gracefully deal
>   with it. Typically used on optional parameters.
>
> When decorating a method, this denotes the method might legitimately
>   return null.
>
> This is a marker annotation and it has no specific attributes.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Nullable.html